# No output for map function in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have these very simple lines of code:

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Marika", "Andreas", "Peter", "Sabine"]

friends.map{
    println("Hallo \($0)!")
}
```

This works fine in a program but I get no output in a playground.
It only tells me the count of the elements and how many times to function needs to run. But it does not write the strings.

Is it me or is this a bug in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug in Xcode.  While your `map` code will print to the standard out (hit cmd-opt-enter to reveal the output in the assistant editor on the right), stylistically you should avoid using `map` for this.  You would be better off with a `for...in` loop:

```
for friend in friends {
    println("Hallo \(friend)")
}
```

If you quick-look the results this time, you'll see a more helpful result: [image: quicklook]

(note, I've switched the quick look to the list view, which shows every result, rather than just the last one)

Why is this working differently?  It's because `map` isn't really for running arbitrary code against your array.  It's more specifically for *transforming* (i.e. mapping) your array into another array.  So suppose instead of printing a list of friends, you wanted a list of greetings, you could do this:

```
let greetings = friends.map { friend in
    "Hallo \(friend)"
}
```

`greetings` will now be set to a new array of 5 strings, one for each name, of the form `"Hallo <name>"`.  `map` is taking a closure that takes a string, and maps it to a new string.

So what is happening when you write `friends.map { println("...") }` is that `map` is calling the closure, and getting the result of the expression in the closure, and populating a new array with it.  Since `println` returns `Void`, the result of that expression each time is `Void`.  And it is that `Void` that Xcode is displaying (as "`(0 elements)`" which is how the UI displays `Void`).

Instead, with the for-loop, Xcode knows that a stand-alone `println` who's value isn't being used should be interpreted not as a result, but as what got output to the standard out, so that's what it does.